# What is the wavelength of gravitational waves?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, wavelength

What is the wavelength of gravitational waves?  I have looked for an answer but so far not identified one.

Comment: I looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave and was going to write an answer, when I suddenly realized that you can read it yourself.

Answer (score 20):

Like electromagnetic waves, gravitational waves can in principle have any wavelength.  They obey the usual relationship $v = \lambda f$ between the wave's speed $v$, wavelength $\lambda$, and frequency $f$.  Einstein's theory predicts (and recent observations have confirmed) that the speed of gravitational waves is $v = c$, regardless of their frequency.  Thus,  higher-frequency waves have shorter wavelengths, and lower-frequency waves have longer wavelengths, just as with electromagnetic waves.

There are two gravitational wave observatories that have detected gravitational waves to date:  LIGO, a large two-site detector in the USA, and Virgo, a smaller one-site detector in Europe.  These detectors are both optimized to detect gravitational waves with frequencies between a few hundred and a few thousand Hertz, so all of the gravitational waves that have been thus far detected are in this range.  Since $\lambda = c/f$, this means that the wavelengths of these waves was in the range of 100-1000 km (give or take.)

Future detectors have been proposed to detect gravitational waves at even lower frequencies (longer wavelengths).  It is expected that many other sources in the universe will generate gravitational waves with longer wavelength (lower frequency) than the ones that have been thus far detected:

[image]

<sup>(Image from [NASA Goddard Flight Center, via Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:The_Gravitational_wave_spectrum_Sources_and_Detectors.jpg))</sup>

Comment: What I'd like to know is, since the wavelength of light is affected *by* gravity, how does this reconcile with the wavelength of gravity waves themselves? For example, do gravity wavelengths change depending on the gravitational field? But then how does that fit with the notion of them as carriers *of* the field?

Comment: @Steve:  That's probably worth asking as a new question;  I wasn't able to find a pithy answer elsewhere on this site.  Basically, though: gravitational waves do get redshifted;  and the fact that "real gravitons" are influenced by gravity is due to the fact that *everything* is influenced by gravity.  In other words, gravity gravitates.

Comment: Thank you very much that is very interesting and helpful

Comment: @Al236:  No problem!  If you think this fully answers your question, feel free to "accept" it by clicking on the check mark button to the left of the answer.